# aggregate function with join by most recent date Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, join, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to select a single test score for students by test type, test element, semester and ID.  One score per ID.  If a student has taken the test more than once, I want to only return the highest (or most recent) score for that test and element.

My problem is that there are a very small number of instances (less than 10 records out of 2000) where a student has two test scores recorded on different dates because they've re-taken the test to improve their score and we record both scores.  My output therefore has a small number of records with multiple scores for unique name_ids (where test_id = 'act' and element_id = 'comp').

Examples of the two tables are:

```
students
----------------------------------------------------------
name_id     term_id

100         Fall
100         Spring
100         Summer
105         Fall
105         Spring
110         Fall
110         Spring
110         Summer

test_score
----------------------------------------------------------
name_id     test_id   element_id    score         test_date

100         act       comp          25            02/01/2019
100         sat       comp          1250          01/20/2019
105         act       comp          19            01/15/2019
105         act       comp          21            02/28/2019
110         act       comp          27            01/31/2019
```

I've tried using MAX(test_score) but perhaps could use MAX(test_date)?  Either would work because the students don't report additional test scores from later dates if the scores aren't higher than what was originally reported.

This is a small part of a larger routine joining several tables so I don't know that I can replace my JOIN(s).  I'm just trying to get this small subset of the routine to produce the correct number of unique records

```
SELECT
       a.name_id NameID,
       a.term_id TermID,
       MAX(b.score) Score

       FROM students a

       LEFT JOIN test_score b ON a.name_id = b.name_id AND b.test_id = 'act' AND b.element_id = 'comp'

     WHERE a.term_id = 'Spring'

     group by b.score,a.name_id,a.term_id
     order by a.name_id
```

No error messages but results from above will yield two records for NameID 105:

```
NameID    TermID    Score
100       Spring    25
105       Spring    19
105       Spring    21
110       Spring    27
```

I'm not certain how to write this to only select the highest score (or only the score from the most recent date)

Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the highest score the GROUP BY cannot include the score...

```
SELECT
       a.name_id NameID,
       a.term_id TermID,
      MAX(b.score) Score

       FROM students a

       LEFT JOIN test_score b ON a.name_id = b.name_id AND b.test_id = 'act' AND b.element_id = 'comp'

    WHERE a.term_id = 'Spring'

     group by a.name_id,a.term_id
     order by a.name_id
```

To get the score associated with the highest date...

```
SELECT x.NameID,
       x.TermID,
       y.score
FROM (
SELECT
       a.name_id NameID,
       a.term_id TermID,
   ---  MAX(b.score) Score
       MAX(b.test_date) test_date

       FROM students a

       LEFT JOIN test_score b ON a.name_id = b.name_id AND b.test_id = 'act' AND b.element_id = 'comp'

    WHERE a.term_id = 'Spring'

     group by a.name_id,a.term_id ) x

     LEFT JOIN test_score y ON x.nameid = y.name_id AND x.test_date = y.test_date
     order by x.nameid
```

Comment: Fabulous, thank you!!  Removing the score field from the Group By eliminated the unwanted rows!